# Problems with SQLITE columns (array) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rails-api

I'm building an API, I have 2 models `User` and `Coin`.

The `Coins` table stores the default coins that can be added to the user's account.

I need to save the coins ids that the user decided to add in a column of the `User` model (`my_coins`), and be able to list only the coins saved by the user.
The problem is that I'm using sqlite3 and I can't save an array in a column

> Routes.rb

```
get '/getCoins', to: "coins#index"
post '/coin/add', to: "users#add_coin"
```

> users_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :validate_jwt # Validates JWT, @current_user
    before_action :user_coins_params

    def add_coin
        coin_acronym = user_coins_params[:id]
        if Coin.find(coin_acronym).exists?

            # @current_user CURRENT USER LOGGED IN ACTIVE RECORD
            # ADD THE ID OF COIN TO MY_COINS COLUMN            

            if # push id of coin to my_coins column success 
                render json: { success: true, message: "Moeda cadastrada com sucesso!" }
            else 
                render json: { success: false, errors: @current_user.errors }
            end
        else
            render json: { success: false, message: "Moeda não encontrada" }
        end
    end

    private
        def user_coins_params
            ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(params)
        end
end
```

> coins_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::CoinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :validate_jwt # VALIDATES JWT, @current_user
  before_action :set_coin, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # /coins GET USER COINS 
  def index    
    @coins = # GET USER COINS (@current_user.my_coins.each { |coinId| ... })
    render json: @coins, include: [:mining_type]
  end

end
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question, but to me, this sounds like a perfect example for a [`has_and_belongs_to_many` association between `users` and `coins`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association). And in that case you will use a `coins_users` join table instead of an array column on users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed above by @spickermann, seems like what you need is a `has and belongs to many associations (HBTM)` in both models `users` and `coins`, I think this approach is a better fit for your problem, is easy to get/update/create any data with this approach, at least I think is better than an array inside a column of your `users` table, in case you want to give it a try here is how I will do it:

So on your `coin` model add the following line:
`has_and_belongs_to_many :users`;
and in your `user` model: `has_and_belongs_to_many :coins`.

Once you added the proper associations to your models you need to generate a `migration` in order to create your `join table`, the code in the migration should look like below:

```rb
create_join_table :users, :coins do |t|
      t.index [:user_id, :coin_id]
      t.index [:coin_id, :user_id]
end
```

The example above is on `rails 5.2`, and with the above, you can do stuff like:

```rb
user1.coins << coin_a
user1.save
```

Then you can iterate over `user1.coins` if you want all the coins related to a particular user ([This link might be helpful](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)).

Hope the above helps !